# create and populate with DOM a checkbox list with array values in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have an array of animals ... how do I manage to create a checkbox list in javascript and fill each with a name of the animals who are in animals array and display them in html.
My my attempt code:

```
var lengthArrayAnimals = animals.length;
for (var i= 0; pos < tamanhoArrayDiagnosticos; pos++) {
    var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
    checkBox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    checkBox.name = diagnosticos[i];
}
```

Comment: You have to append the `checkBox` to the DOM

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one way (pure JavaScript, no jQuery):

```
var animals = ["lion", "tigers", "bears", "squirrels"];

var myDiv = document.getElementById("cboxes");

for (var i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
    var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
    var label = document.createElement("label");
    checkBox.type = "checkbox";
    checkBox.value = animals[i];
    myDiv.appendChild(checkBox);
    myDiv.appendChild(label);
    label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(animals[i]));
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lemoncurry/5brxz3mk/

Comment: super. This helps a lot.

Answer (score 5):

I hope this is what you expected.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var animals=["cat","dog","pikachu","charmaner"];

$.each(animals,function(index,value){
 var checkbox="<label for="+value+">"+value+"</label><input type='checkbox' id="+value+" value="+value+" name="+value+">"
 $(".checkBoxContainer").append($(checkbox));
})

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkBoxContainer"></div>
```