# How to populate a checkbox list in HTML from a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, checkbox, web-applications

I have an array in JavaScript(array is created from a google sheet[program is in apps script]) that I would like turn into options in a checkbox, making each value in the array a checkbox option. FYI, the checkbox will be displayed in a HTML web app. How do I do this?

Comment: Please check this example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28678027/create-and-populate-with-dom-a-checkbox-list-with-array-values-in-javascript

Comment: Use a loop that created `input` elements and appends them to the DOM.

Comment: What exactly are you calling a "checkbox"?  I only ask because you use the phrase "options in a checkbox", and checkboxes do not have options.

Comment: @Taplar I think he means checkboxes that represent options. Like checkboxes for all the toppings on a pizza.

Comment: I hope so, but would like to get clarification to be sure.